# How to zip my file in azure fileshare using FileShareClient?

Tags: azure, azure-files, fileshare

I need to zip my file in fileshare. I have gone through few process and they all suggested methods for blob. Any link or advice that would be helpful for me to proceed?

I can't use Azure Data Factory because of cost issue and I have already gone through these links: [link1](https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/) and [link2](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip141.html). In these link they have used `blockblobclient.downloadto` method which is not present in `fileshareclient`

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Data Factory, it supports Azure Blob Storage (*see link below*).
This is a better approach, but as you mention, there is a tutorial that can help you with zipping files and storing them to Azure Storage.

**Tutorial:** https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/

**Supported formats:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats

**Using Data Factory:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal

Comment: I know I can use Data Factory but that will add extra cost to the project and in JOSEF tutorial, I have already seen it. Its very blob specific like in this tutorial it used ```blockblobclient.downloadto``` method. There is no such method in ```fileshareclient```

Comment: You didn't mention cost problems in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll make the change